# open page new tab and refresh current page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), null, "window.open('bill_reciept.aspx?Parameter=" + txt_billNo.Text + "', '_newtab')", true);
```

this is new page in tab

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), null, "window.open('customerReg.aspx', '_self')", true);
```

This old page that want to refresh

new page is getting opened in tab but old page cannot refresh or open in a new page in same tab

Comment: for the second you can use location.reload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

You can redirect on the same page using following code :

```
Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
```

If you want to do on clientside and not the server, use

```
 javascript:document.location.reload()
```

or

```
window.location.href= window.location;
```

I have referred following link, you can do the same:

[http://forums.asp.net/t/1310604.aspx?+How+to+refresh+the+page+programatically+by+C+](http://forums.asp.net/t/1310604.aspx?%20How%20to%20refresh%20the%20page%20programatically%20by%20C%20)

Answer (score 1):

Do something like below...

Call javascript method like below...

```
var windowObjectReference;

function openRequestedPopup() {
    windowObjectReference = window.open("CMS_1.aspx",
          "DescriptiveWindowName",
          "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
}
```

This will open page in new tab, and in end of function you have to reload location....